# How can I apply a XSLT template to several different elements with the same structure?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I have scoured Google and Stack Overflow and have been unable to find an answer to this. So I apologize if this is a duplicate.

I have an XML document that has some nested types; however, several repeating elements appear throughout the document all with different names and parents. When compared to the XSD, these repeating elements are actually found to be the same type of object, just referenced throughout. There are about 50 different types that reference this repeating element. How can I write one template that can then be called from inside of each of the 50 templates I need to write so that I don't have to duplicate the transform for each parent type?

For example:

```html
<Model1>
  <Description>desc1</Description>
  <Code>code1</Code>
  <type>VMO</type>
  <Model2>
    <Description>desc1</Description>
    <Code>code1</Code>
    <type>VMO</type>
  </Model2>
</Model1>
<Model3>
  <Description>desc1</Description>
  <Code>code1</Code>
  <type>VMO</type>
  <Model4>
    <Model5>
      <Description>desc1</Description>
      <Code>code1</Code>
      <type>VMO</type>
      <Model6>
        <Description>desc1</Description>
        <Code>code1</Code>
        <type>VMO</type>
      </Model6>
    </Model5>
    <Code>code1</Code>
    <type>VMO</type>
  </Model4>
</Model3>
<Model7>
  <Description>desc1</Description>
  <Code>code1</Code>
  <type>VMO</type>
  <Model8>
    <Description>desc1</Description>
    <Code>code1</Code>
    <type>VMO</type>
  </Model8>
</Model7>
```

In the example above for instance, `Model2`, `Model6` and `Model8` are the same structure and I need to apply the same transform to each element. I would like to do something like this:

```html
<xsl:template match="Model1">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- maps all other elements -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="someSpecialFunction(Model3)" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Model5">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- maps all other elements -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="someSpecialFunction(Model6)" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Model7">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- maps all other elements -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="someSpecialFunction(Model8)" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and simply transform the parent elements. Is this possible?

I know I could do something like this:

```html
<xsl:template match="Model1/Model3">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- Transfrom type -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Model5/Model6">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- Transfrom type -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Model7/Model8">
  <xsl:copy>
    <!-- Transfrom type -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

but then I am repeating a lot of code. Any advice?

**Edit:**

I was too general in my original post, sorry about that.
A more concrete example (and in my case, is one of the objects I have) would be with an address and the sub types associated with them. Several different types of elements have an address. For example, I have a Product element that has a Seller, Supplier, Re-seller, a list of stakeholder each with an address, etc. Each one of these addresses has a different name.

```html
<Product>
  <Seller>
    <BusinessAddress>...</BusinessAddress>
    <DistributionAddress>...</DistributionAddress>
    <MainContactAddress>...</MainContactAddress>
  </Seller>
  <ReSeller>
    <BusinessAddress>...</BusinessAddress>
    <StoreManagerAddress>...</StoreManagerAddress>
    <MainContactAddress>...</MainContactAddress>
  </ReSeller>
  <Supplier>
    <BusinessAddress>...</BusinessAddress>
    <DistributionCenterAddress>...</DistributionCenterAddress>
    <MainContactAddress>...</MainContactAddress>
  </Supplier>
  <Stakeholders>
    <Entity>
      <HomeAddress>...</HomeAddress>
      <WorkAddress>...</WorkAddress>
      <SecondaryAddress>...</SecondaryAddress>
      <Street>...</Street>
      <CrossStreet>...</CrossStreet>
    </Entity>
  </Stakeholders>
</Product>
<SurveyRespondents>
  <SurveyRespondent>
    <Address>...</Address>
    <Business>...</Business>
  </SurveyRespondent>
  <SurveyRespondent>
    <Address>...</Address>
    <Business>...</Business>
  </SurveyRespondent>
</SurveyRespondents>
```

Now this isn't all of the elements that have addresses, but if I go with the approaches I have done before I would have to either make a list of templates (like I mentioned above) or go with a long list of matches like michael.hor257k suggested.

```html
<xsl:template match="Address | Business | SecondaryAddress | WorkAddress | Home | SecondaryAddress | BusinessAddress | ...">
  <!-- apply the same transform to all of these -->
</xsl:template>
```

To compound my problem each address is made up of multiple sub-types: AddressCategory, District, Zone, Street, StreetType, PostDirection, PreDirection, etc. Each one of these types has the same structure, but now I run into the problem of how to I match against every type. Some sub types, like `Street`, are a string in some places (when used in other elements) and a "CodeType" in others. If I do a match I wind up with something really ugly and I am not even done with the whole document yet:

```html
<xsl:template match="Address | Business | SecondaryAddress | WorkAddress | Home | SecondaryAddress | BusinessAddress | ...">
  <!-- apply the same transform to all of these -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Address/Street | Business/Street | SecondaryAddress/Street | WorkAddress/Street | Home/Street | SecondaryAddress/Street | BusinessAddress/Street | AddressType | District | Zone...">
  <!-- apply the same transform to all of these -->
</xsl:template>
```

Am I stuck with a hard to read, debug, and maintain xslt of is the a better way to do this?

Comment: I didn't get the problem with the Street; could you expand your example to show the two types you are talking about?

Comment: This question is a bit cumbersome to read and understand.  I'd recommend getting rid of you original content and simplifying your added edit to clarify what you're trying to accomplish and what your concerns are.  Right now it sounds like you don't like a big list of unions, but it's not clear why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question, because it's all about context - and you are not providing the full context.

> In the example above for instance, Model2, Model6 and Model8 are the
>   same structure and I need to apply the same transform to each element

Why don't you do:

```
<xsl:template match="Model2 | Model6 |  Model8">
    <!-- apply the same transform to all of these -->
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this template can be applied from any node that is a parent of 
a Model2 and/or Model6 and/or  Model8 (actually, it can be applied from other contexts too, but that's probably not the point here).

> How can I write one template that can then be called from inside of
>   each of the 50 templates I need to write

Are you sure you need to write 50 templates?

---

**Re your edit:**

The alternative to:

```
<xsl:template match="Address | Business | SecondaryAddress | WorkAddress | Home | SecondaryAddress | BusinessAddress | ...">
    <!-- apply the same transform to all of these -->
</xsl:template>
```

would be:

```
<xsl:template name="address">
    <xsl:param name="address-node" />
    <!-- apply the transform  -->
</xsl:template>
```

but then you would have to call this template explicitly from each location where an address exists, for example:

```
<xsl:template match="Seller">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- other code -->
        <xsl:call-template name="address">
            <xsl:with-param name="address-node" select="BusinessAddress"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="address">
            <xsl:with-param name="address-node" select="DistributionAddress"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="address">
            <xsl:with-param name="address-node" select="MainContactAddress"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <!-- more code -->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Possibly, this could be shortened to:

```
<xsl:template match="Seller">
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- other code -->
        <xsl:call-template name="address">
            <xsl:with-param name="address-nodes" select="BusinessAddress | DistributionAddress | MainContactAddress"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <!-- more code -->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Even so, I am not sure the alternative is more attractive than the original suggestion.

Comment: My problem is actually much larger, but I was trying to keep it simple in the post. Seems like I went too far. I revised my post above.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a schema-aware XSLT 2.0 processor, this becomes very straightforward. You can define a template rule that matches all elements with a given type `T` like this:

```
<xsl:template match="element(*, T)">
```

or if the elements are all defined in the schema as belonging to a substitution group whose head is element `H`, you can write

```
<xsl:template match="schema-element(H)">
```

Without a schema-aware processor, you have to define a union pattern

```
<xsl:template match="A|B|C|D|E|F....">
```

and remember to change it every time the schema changes.

Comment: Do you know of a .NET object or an open source solution that works with schema-aware transforms? All the tools that I can find require a licence or offer only a limited free version.

Comment: I do not know of any free schema-aware XSLT 2.0 processors, but I do know of a commercial one that comes with phenomenal free advice.